# No tag wikis when asking question in app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I noticed something apparently missing from the app. I recently posted a question from the app and was trying to find out if a certain tag was appropriate for that question. However, I couldn't find a way to view the tag wiki. This would be a nice feature

Comment: Might be worth you changing the "feature-request" tag here to "discussion", as you are *asking* if the app has no tag wikis.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not missing anything (but correct me if I am). Other than that, yes, it is a feature request.

Comment: You can currently only look at a tag wiki when viewing questions belonging to that tag.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I'm talking about viewing them while asking a question. It is really useful sometimes to be able to make sure the tag is appropriate before posting.

Comment: @kittycat3141 gotcha, yeah this is a great feature request!

Answer (score 2):

This will be added in 1.4.3.3.

The tag picker will have a detail accessory which takes you to the full tag wiki.